How to precisely syncronise time at few devices with different response delays?
I have few stations that register some events and sends info about it to server. Server needs to know precise time when that event was registered by each station. Stations can be located at different distances from server and have different delays of response. Stations can be connected to the same server by optic fiber, by radio or by internet (different stations use different methods).
How can be time at each station syncronised with server precisely? Or what can server do to know at which moment each event was happened?
Is there any algorithms for that?
